# Python + Weaved Simple Messaging

Tags: sockets, python-3.x, networking, raspberry-pi2, iot

I'm working on a personal project where I want a PC to send a message to a Raspberry Pi. Since they are not going to be in the same network and I don't want to work with port forwarding, I tried using Weaved; however, I can't get the Raspberry Pi to receive any of the messages I'm sending from the PC.

The code for the Pi looks like this:

```
   # Message Receiver
import os
from socket import *
host = ""
port = 13000
buf = 1024
addr = (host, port)
UDPSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
UDPSock.bind(addr)
print "Waiting to receive messages..."
while True:
    (data, addr) = UDPSock.recvfrom(buf)
    print "Received message: " + data
    if data == "exit":
        break
UDPSock.close()
```

For the PC the code looks like this:

```
# Message Sender
import os
from socket import *
host = "127.0.0.1" # set to IP address of target computer
port = 13000
addr = (host, port)
UDPSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
while True:
    data = raw_input("Enter message to send or type 'exit': ")
    UDPSock.sendto(data, addr)
    if data == "exit":
        break
UDPSock.close()
os._exit(0)
```

I've configuered the Weaved service to custom. I really need help, but I'm not sure that what I am doing is right.

The logic is correct in some way, because this works if the PC is in the same network as the Pi.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Just wondering, have you enabled the Internet client/Private network client capability in your project manifest file?

Comment: I was able to fix the problem. It was something else entirely. Instead of using TCP, I was actually using UDP. @Jackie I didn't even touch the manifest file, don't think it was needed. Thank you for the help anyway.